# How to try-catch inside a method with a return type of Task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following method (abbreviated for simplicity):

```
public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(connection.Execute("CreateUser", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
    }
 }
```

I would like to incorporate a `try-catch block`, so I can log any potential Sql errors.

```
public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
     var result = ???; // what is the return type here?
     try
     {
         result = FromResult(connection.Execute("CreateUser", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
      }
      catch(SqlException sqlEx)
      {
          // log error here
       }

      return result;
}
```

I guess I'm not sure what the return type of `Task` is?

Comment: The return type would be Task<T> and T is determined by the return type of connection.Execute(...). Please consider, that Task.FromResult(...) is still synchronous. If you want it async you can use Task.Run(...) or an async method of the connection object.

Comment: I fail to see what the purpose of returning `Task` would be here, your method implementation is not async in the slightest, can you elaborate?

Comment: The call to this method is: `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen From the signature, the OP is implementing a custom UserStore, implementing ASP.NET Identity's `IUserStore<TUser>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use async methods instead of `Task.FromResult`.
I'm assuming you are using Dapper or some kind of framework that extends `SqlConnection`.
I have no idea what the stored procedure returns. If the return value doesn't matter then the code should look like this.

```
public async Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
     try
     {
         await connection.ExecuteAsync("CreateUser", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     }
     catch(SqlException sqlEx)
     {
         // log error here
     }
}
```

if it does matter then (example with bool):

```
public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
     bool result;
     try
     {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync("CreateUser", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        result = true;
     }
     catch(SqlException sqlEx)
     {
         // log error here
        result = false;
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using dapper

Comment: @PixelPaul - Then you can consider using the QueryAsync<T> method instead of ExecuteAsync. The benefit is that you can return stuff from your stored proc.
https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2018/01/28/using-stored-procedures-to-load-data-with-dapper.aspx